# Form Control Validation for User Input in (VB.NET 2005)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, validation

I am writing an application for my Notary business. I am a Notary Public in Iowa.

I have many types of control on the form. ComboBox (that can be modified), TextBox and MaskedTextBox.
I know I can use the TextBoxBase class to cover the TextBox and also the MaskedTextBox, but my validation code is not doing anything. Nothing happens.

I have an ErrorProvider on the form called ErrorProvider. It has the "AutoValidate" option set to "EnableAllowFocusChange". The BlinkStyle is set to AlwaysBlink. All other properties are default.

I have three buttons on the form, too. Reset, Save and Close. Both the Reset and Close buttons are set to CausesValidation = False and the Save button is set to CausesValidation = True.

I need to make sure the "required" fields have a value when the Save button is clicked.

So, I figured I would use the Validated and Validating events of the controls. But, when clicking Save, nothing happens. The ErrorProvider doesnt even show. If I leave the control empty, still nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
    Private Sub Company_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles Company.Validated, CompanyAddress.Validated, CompanyCity.Validated, CompanyZipCode.Validated, CompanyPhone.Validated, CompanyAddressRemit.Validated, CompanyCityRemit.Validated, CompanyZipCodeRemit.Validated
    ErrorProvider.SetError(CType(sender, TextBoxBase), String.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub Company_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
Handles Company.Validating, CompanyAddress.Validating, CompanyCity.Validating, CompanyZipCode.Validating, CompanyPhone.Validating, CompanyAddressRemit.Validating, CompanyCityRemit.Validating, CompanyZipCodeRemit.Validating
    Dim ErrorMessage As String = String.Empty
    Dim TheField As TextBoxBase = CType(sender, TextBoxBase)

    If TypeOf TheField Is MaskedTextBox Then
        CType(TheField, MaskedTextBox).TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals
    End If

    If Not IsValid(TheField, ErrorMessage) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        TheField.Select(0, TheField.Text.Length)
        ErrorProvider.SetError(TheField, ErrorMessage)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsValid(ByVal ControlName As TextBoxBase, ByVal ErrorMessage As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ControlName.Text.ToString) Then
        ErrorMessage = "This is a required field."
        Return False
    Else
        ErrorMessage = String.Empty
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) class in `vb.net` is a bit "odd". It's a reference type that acts (not all cases) like a value type. You need to change `ByVal` to `ByRef`.

```
Private Function IsValid(ByVal ControlName As TextBoxBase, ByRef ErrorMessage As String) As Boolean
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I was working on this for hours and didn't even notice that small change. The form is now validating, by what I can tell. So, if all required fields have a value and you click the Save button, the information needs to be put into a database. To check this validity, I would check if IsValid = true, and if so, then add the values, right?

Comment: @PadraigMacUidhir Before you save call `Me.Validate()`. If it returns a `True` value then you're good to go.